# How to define a function without a name in modern JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, you can define an anonymous function with function keyword or an arrow function. But now JavaScript is smart enough to recognize if the function is assigned to a variable and give it a name:

```js
const foo = function() { };
console.log(foo.name);
```

Is there a way to actually define a function without a name and save it inside a variable?

I need this for my [Scheme interpreter](https://lips.js.org/) where I have a function curry:

```js
function curry(fn, ...init_args) {
    typecheck('curry', fn, 'function');
    var len = fn.length;
    return function() {
        var args = init_args.slice();
        const curried = (...more_args) => {
            args = args.concat(more_args);
            if (args.length >= len) {
                return fn.apply(this, args);
            } else {
                return curried;
            }
        };
        return curried(...arguments);
    };
}
```

And I don't want the current function to show the name when printed:

```lisp
(define (sum a b c)
  (+ a b c))

(define add1 (curry sum))

(print (add1 2))
;; ==> #<procedure:curried>
```

I want the curried procedure to be shown and `#<procedure>` for this I need a function to actually be anonymous and don't have a name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an IIFE to get rid of the name:

```js
function curry(fn, ...init_args) {
    typecheck('curry', fn, 'function');
    var len = fn.length;
    return function() {
        var args = init_args.slice();
        // HACK: we use IIFE here to get rid of the name of the function.
        // The JavaScript is smart and add name property to a function
        // if it's assigned to a variable, with IIFE we can get rid of it.
        const curried = (() => {
            return (...more_args) => {
                args = args.concat(more_args);
                if (args.length >= len) {
                    return fn.apply(this, args);
                } else {
                    return curried;
                }
            };
        })()
        return curried(...arguments);
    };
}
```